# classification by multiple samples

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I have trained a SVM classifier for image-based construction material classification. It's a two class classifier to distinguish concrete and brick for now. My input to this classifier is some color plus texture histogram generated from a 50*50 image patch.

Now what if I can have multiple image patches which I believe they are the same material (imagine I random sample some image patches from a concrete wall surface), and I want to do classification on these multiple samples to get a single conclusion, like this is a concrete wall. The most straight forward way to me is do classification on every candidate image patches and pick the majority result as my conclusion. But is there some other better way to do this? Like some kind of weighting or voting strategy? Thanks.

Comment: depends on what you want to answer
"most of the image is concrete" or "20% of the image is clearly concrete" etc

Comment: Thanks. I may not state my goal clearly. I extract image patches from a wall surface which I assume is made of one material. So I have multiple candidate samples for my SVM classifier now. I can do classfication multiple times and pick the dominant results as my conclusion. Yes, this is a concrete wall. But do I have better strategy for classification considering I have large resource of samples which should give me better classification result? A weighting of every single classification result? A voting scheme? Or I actually mix my multiple samples as a single one somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the confidence of the SVM. Count the number of times it was classified as "concrete", but weigh it by the confidence of the SVM. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, the confidence. That's what comes to mind at the first place. Thank you. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that brick pattern and concrete are pretty different visually so using SVM may be an overkill. There are many other machine learning methods such as, for example, a Kmeans. They may be simpler but even so may work better.

May be just plotting your feature vectors for two classes in  multidemsional space would create two distinct clouds so measuring distance from the centers of these clouds (normalized by standard deviation) will give you the answer and more clear understanding of what's going on.

One the difference between Kmeans and SVM is that [Kmeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) builds a prototype of the object while  SVM collects some exemplar that aren't even representative but just lie close to the border between two classes. OpenCV has the implementaiton of [Kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html?highlight=kmeans#cv2.kmeans)

Performing PCA on the feature difference may give you the most distinct dimensions. This can simplify your algorithm and feature extraction.

Comment: I actually have more types of material to be recognized. Brick and concrete are just the beginning. But yes, I get your point. As a greenhand in machine learning, I may have not formed my solution in a reasonable way.

Comment: My advice to you as a greenhand - start with building object prototypes (K-means, Mixture of Gaussians) rather than finding boundaries (SVM, trees). The former methods are easier to understand and it can also may help you to select the right features before engaging in more complex methods.